Agregarle color a cuadro de texto en CSS
No sé cómo agregarle color dentro los cuadros de texto en css. Cada cuadro debe llevar un color específico dependiendo de la letra seleccionada en cada cuadro. Es para un juego al estilo Wordle.
    .letter {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 3px;
      min-width: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block
  }


Tal vez al fondo con background o al texto con color.

El color lo pones con la propiedad CSS background-color


  .letterR {
      background-color:green;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 3px;
      min-width: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block
  }
  
    .letterG {
      background-color:red;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 3px;
      min-width: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block
  }
<div class="letterR">Color Rojo</div>

<div class="letterG">Color Verde</div>



